# Mac mini won't start in any mode. Looks to be some kind of disk failure

Tags: macos, mac-mini

We got a strange trouble. My sister has a mac mini, and it for same reason stopped working. Tried to restart it in any possible mode. Can't restart even from a bootable USB stick with mac OS, making it impossible to be erased or fixed. Only mode that started is single user mode ( command  line ) where the disk could not be fixed. But, I saw that in single user mode, I can list directories and files. So, the disk looks to be working.

What makes it even more bizarre, is that when plugged this disk as a external disk on another mac computer it restarts immediately and shows the black screen of death. ( that one that says "this computer restarted because of a problem").

Is this a physical disk failure? Any ideas? Never seen anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Right after the **root#** prompt, enter the following:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

Press the **Return** key.

**Background:** You can repair a drive by using the **fsck** command. Fsck stands for **File System Check (the name is sometimes referred to as File System Consistency ChecK)**; it can be used with various optional parameters.

It will take a few minutes.

In the end, if your drive was OK, the screen will say “**The volume (name of your hard drive) appears to be OK**”. If any repair was made, you’ll see the prompt, “**FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED**”. Then, you’ll see the root# prompt again.

Right after the root# prompt, enter the following:

```
reboot
```

Press the Return key. Your Mac should restart normally. Let me know how it goes.